# Converting an array of RGB colours to a px.imshow heatmap

Tags: arrays, dataframe, plotly, rgb, imshow

I currently have a DF of different RGB colour values in this format:

```
          Protein_ID1  Protein_ID2  Protein_ID3
Module1    [R, G, B]    [R, G, B]    [R, G, B]    
Module2    [R, G, B]    [R, G, B]    [R, G, B]    
Module3    [R, G, B]    [R, G, B]    [R, G, B]
```

I would like to display this with px.imshow as a eat map, with the cell colour corresponding to the RGB value.

When I do:

```
fig = px.imshow(df)
fig.update_layout(
                  xaxis=dict(
                             rangeslider=dict(visible=True)
                            )
                 )
fig.write_html(results_file)
```

I get nothing in the blank results file.  Based on the first example [here](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/), I converted my df to an array as below and still had no luck:

```
array = df.to_numpy()
fig = px.imshow(array, x = df.columns, y = df.index)
fig.update_layout(
                  xaxis=dict(
                             rangeslider=dict(visible=True)
                            )
                 )
fig.write_html(results_file)
```

Can anyone shed some light on the correct way to approach this?

Thanks!
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- core is get input to `px.imshow()` correct.  It needs to be a 3D numpy array of type uint8
- hence get values out of data frame and restructure to input requirements

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# simulate data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 255, [10, 10, 3]).tolist(),
    columns=[f"Protein_ID{i}" for i in range(10)],
    index=[f"Module{i}" for i in range(10)],
)

px.imshow(np.array(df.values.tolist(), dtype=np.uint8)).show()

print(df.iloc[0:3, 0:3].to_markdown())
```

#### sample data

|  | Protein_ID0 | Protein_ID1 | Protein_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Module0 | [232, 78, 62] | [96, 105, 104] | [138, 63, 46] |
| Module1 | [143, 49, 25] | [190, 70, 138] | [77, 170, 155] |
| Module2 | [16, 209, 3] | [153, 215, 47] | [216, 246, 121] |

#### image

[image]

#### with labels

```
px.imshow(np.array(df.values.tolist(), dtype=np.uint8)).update_layout(
    xaxis={"tickformat": "array", "tickvals": list(range(10)), "ticktext": df.columns},
    yaxis={"tickformat": "array", "tickvals": list(range(10)), "ticktext": df.index}

)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, this works perfectly.  I'll accept as it answered the questions posed, but I've realised the question wasn't complete.  Is it possible to set non-numeric x/y axes, ideally with the x/y values appearing in the hover text?  Earlier iterations of what im trying to do, using dataframes, did this automatically (but failed for other reasons)

Comment: updated with how to add labels